# Save inventory it is not visually displayed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem displaying items in the inventory and perhaps also not very correct saving of items. Items are not visible visually, they are added to the list. I don't know what the problem might be. Most likely in the script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform itemsParent;

    InventorySlot[] slots;

    EquipmentManager equipmentManager;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
      
        equipmentManager = EquipmentManager.Instance;
        equipmentManager.LoadEquipment();


        Inventory.Instance.onItemChangedCallback += UpdateUI;

        slots = itemsParent.GetComponentsInChildren<InventorySlot>();

        // Updates the UI when the script starts
        UpdateUI(); 

    }

     void UpdateUI()
    {
      
        for (int i = 0;i < slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < Inventory.Instance.items.Count)
            {
                slots[i].AddItem(Inventory.Instance.items[i]);
            }
            else
            {
               slots[i].ClearSlot();
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
         ***this Item create have Sprite***     
        using UnityEngine;
        
        [System.Serializable]
        [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Inventory/Item")]
        public class Item : ScriptableObject
        {
            new public string name = "New Item";
            [TextArea(4,10)]
            public string description = "Item description"; 
            public Sprite icon = null;
            public bool idDefaulItem = false;
          
        
            public virtual void Use()
            {
                Debug.Log("Using " + name);
            }
        
            public void RemoveFromInventory()
            {
                Inventory.Instance.Remove(this);
            }
        }
    
    
    ***This Inventory scrip for save load items***

    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.IO;
    using TMPro;
    
    public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Singleton
    
        public static Inventory Instance;
    
        private void Awake()
        {
           Instance = this;
            LoadInventory();
        }
        #endregion
        // Event handler for when items are changed
        public delegate void OnItemChanged();
        public OnItemChanged onItemChangedCallback;
    
        public int slots = 20;
        public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        float coinValue;
        private void Start()
        {
            LoadInventory();
           
        }
        public bool Add(Item item)
        {
            if (items.Count >= slots)
            {
                Debug.Log("Inventory is full");
                return false;
            }
    
            items.Add(item);
            SaveInventory();
            if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
                onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
          
            return true;
        }
    
        public void Remove(Item item)
        {
            items.Remove(item);
            SaveInventory();
            if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
                onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
          
        }
        public void RemoveAllItems()
        {
            items.Clear();
            SaveInventory();
            if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
                onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
          
        }
        public void ClearInventory()
        {
            items.Clear();
            SaveInventory();
            if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
                onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
           
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            
        }
        public void SellRandomValue()
        {
            int coinValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins");
            int randomCoin = 0;
    
            if (items.Count >= 1)
            {
                randomCoin = Random.Range(1, 5);
            }
            if (items.Count >= 5)
            {
                randomCoin = Random.Range(5, 15);
            }
            if (items.Count >= 10)
            {
                randomCoin = Random.Range(10, 25);
            }
    
            coinValue += randomCoin; // Add the random coin value to the current coin value
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", coinValue);
        }
        public void SaveInventory()
        {
            // Convert the inventory data to a JSON string
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
    
            // Define the file path for the save file using the persistent data path
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "inventory_save.txt");
    
            // Write the JSON string to the file
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
    
            Debug.Log("Inventory saved to " + filePath);
    
        }
    
        public void LoadInventory()
        {
            // Define the file path for the save file using the persistent data path
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "inventory_save.txt");
    
            // Check if the save file exists
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // Read the JSON string from the file
                string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    
                // Convert the JSON string back to inventory data
                JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, this);
    
                Debug.Log("Inventory loaded from " + filePath);
    
    
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("No inventory save file found");
            }
    
    
            if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
            {
                onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
            }
        }
        void OnApplicationQuit()
        {
            SaveInventory();
        }
    }

***This InventorySlot for selected item and info items*** 
using System;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class InventorySlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image icon;
    public Button removeButton;
    Item item;
    AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip UseItemClip;

    public TextMeshProUGUI itemNameText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI equipSlotText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI armorModifierText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI damageModifierText;

    public TextMeshProUGUI DescriptionText;

    public GameObject ButtonEquipImage;
    public GameObject DpsImage;
    public GameObject MoveSpeedImage;
    public GameObject ArmorImage;

    public GameObject GreenDPS;
    public GameObject RedDPS;

    public GameObject GreenArmor;
    public GameObject RedArmor;
    public Equipment selectedEquipment; 
    public Button equipButton;
    public Button equipButton1;
    public Image SelectedItem;

    public Inventory selectedInventory;
    public static InventorySlot SelectedSlot;
    public UITweenSwipeInfo uiSwipeInfo;
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        equipButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonEquip); 
        equipButton1.onClick.AddListener(TransferToChest); 
    }

    public void AddItem(Item newItem)
    {
        if (newItem != null)
        {
            item = newItem;

            icon.sprite = newItem.icon;
            icon.enabled = true;

            removeButton.interactable = true;
        }


    }

    public void ClearSlot()
    {
        item = null;

        icon.sprite = null;
        icon.enabled = false;

        removeButton.interactable = false;

        OnRemoveButton();
    }

    public void OnRemoveButton()
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            Inventory.Instance.Remove(item);
        }
    }
    public void RemoveAll()
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            Inventory.Instance.ClearInventory();
        }
    }

    public void UseItem()
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(UseItemClip);
            item.Use();


        }
    }
    public void ButtonEquip()
    {
        if (selectedEquipment != null)
        {
            if (selectedEquipment != null)
            {

                EquipmentManager.Instance.EquipSelected(selectedEquipment);

            }
            selectedEquipment = null;

       
            ClearItemDetails();
            uiSwipeInfo.ReturnPanel();
        }
    }



    public void DisplayItemDetails()
    {
      
        if (item is Equipment equipment)
        {
       
            ButtonEquipImage.SetActive(true);
            DpsImage.SetActive(true);
            MoveSpeedImage.SetActive(true);
            ArmorImage.SetActive(true);
            DescriptionText.text = "";
            selectedEquipment = equipment;
            itemNameText.text = equipment.name;
            equipSlotText.text = equipment.equipSlot.ToString();
            armorModifierText.text = equipment.armorModifier.ToString();
            damageModifierText.text = equipment.damageModifier.ToString();

           
            Equipment equippedItemInSlot = EquipmentManager.Instance.GetEquippedItemInSlot(equipment.equipSlot);
            SelectedSlot = this;
           
            equipButton.interactable = true; 
            equipButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners(); 
            equipButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonEquip); /
            equipButton1.onClick.AddListener(TransferToChest); 
          uiSwipeInfo.PanelSwipe(); 
            if (equippedItemInSlot != null)
            {
               


                // Сравниваем характеристики
                if (equipment.armorModifier > equippedItemInSlot.armorModifier)
                {
                    armorModifierText.color = Color.green;
                    GreenArmor.SetActive(true);
                    RedArmor.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (equipment.armorModifier < equippedItemInSlot.armorModifier)
                {
                    armorModifierText.color = Color.red;
                    RedArmor.SetActive(true);
                    GreenArmor.SetActive(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    armorModifierText.color = Color.white;
                    GreenArmor.SetActive(false);
                    RedArmor.SetActive(false);

                }

                if (equipment.damageModifier > equippedItemInSlot.damageModifier)
                {
                    damageModifierText.color = Color.green;
                    GreenDPS.SetActive(true);
                    RedDPS.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (equipment.damageModifier < equippedItemInSlot.damageModifier)
                {
                    damageModifierText.color = Color.red;
                    GreenDPS.SetActive(false);
                    RedDPS.SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    damageModifierText.color = Color.white;
                    GreenDPS.SetActive(false);
                    RedDPS.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
                armorModifierText.color = Color.green;
                damageModifierText.color = Color.green;
                GreenArmor.SetActive(true);
                RedArmor.SetActive(false);
                GreenDPS.SetActive(true);
                RedDPS.SetActive(false);
            }


        }
        else if (item is Item genericItem)
        {
            SelectedSlot = this;
            uiSwipeInfo.PanelSwipe(); 
                                      
            itemNameText.text = genericItem.name;
            DescriptionText.text = genericItem.description;

            ButtonEquipImage.SetActive(false);
            DpsImage.SetActive(false);
            MoveSpeedImage.SetActive(false);
            ArmorImage.SetActive(false);

            GreenArmor.SetActive(false);
            RedArmor.SetActive(false);
            GreenDPS.SetActive(false);
            RedDPS.SetActive(false);

            equipSlotText.text = "Treasure"; 
            armorModifierText.text = ""; 
            damageModifierText.text = ""; 
        }
    }
    public void ClearItemDetails()
    {
        itemNameText.text = "";
        equipSlotText.text = "";
        armorModifierText.text = "";
        damageModifierText.text = "";
    
    }
    public void TransferToChest()
    {
        if (SelectedSlot != null && SelectedSlot.item != null)
        {
            if (Chest.Instance.Add(SelectedSlot.item))
            {
                Inventory.Instance.Remove(SelectedSlot.item);
                SelectedSlot.ClearSlot();

               
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: This seems to be rather a part of your question, not an answer ... please [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77034579/edit) and rather insert this additional information there

Comment: Why is your `Item` a `ScriptapleObject`? It is not allowed to create instances of those using `new` which is what the `JsonUtility` internally needs to do to create instances of that class ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).